# Programmatically focusing on InputField and opening up keyboard

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a situation where I need to programmatically focus on a [InputField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputField-class.html)(such as in response to a button press).

I'm using the [Focus.moveTo](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Focus/moveTo.html) function; however, even though the InputField is focused (blinking cursor appears) the keyboard is not brought up.

It seems like the best solution would be to call the [RequestKeyboard()](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input.dart#L108) function in _InputFieldState, but this is private.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Here is a code sample showing the workflow:

```
class InputFieldWrapper extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _InputFieldWrapperState createState() => new _InputFieldWrapperState();
}


class _InputFieldWrapperState extends State<InputFieldWrapper> {

  InputValue _currentInput = new InputValue(text: 'hello');

  // GlobalKey for the InputField so we can focus on it
  GlobalKey<EditableTextState> _inputKey = new GlobalKey<EditableTextState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: [
        // Button that should focus on the InputField when pressed
        new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.message),
          onPressed: () {
            Focus.moveTo(_inputKey);
          },
        ),
        // InputField that should be focused when pressing the Button
        new InputField(
          value: _currentInput,
          key: _inputKey,
          onChanged: (InputValue input) {
            setState(() {
              _currentInput = input;
            });
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Filed a bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7985

Answer (score 1):

This was decided to be a bug and is being tracked at [#7985](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7985).